Hide a specific label from appearing on the Blogger homepage
I want to hide specific labels from the homepage, so I replaced this code:
<b:include data='post' name='post'/>

with this code:
<b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
    <b:if cond='data:post.labels none (l => l.name == "مقالات")'>
        <b:include data='post' name='post'/>
    </b:if>
</b:loop>

Indeed, the labels I wanted to hide have disappeared, but the issue of repeated articles has arisen! Each article is repeated three times as seen in the picture. Can someone help me? Thank you.

